# JDBC "database table is locked" error

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, locking

I am developing a simple Java library that will provide database access. Currently I am working on accessing SQLite. I have a class named SQlite.java which only implements instance methods. Below are the implementation of a few methods:

```
public ResultSet retrieve(String query) {
    try {
        if (this.connection != null) {
            this.statement = this.connection.createStatement();
            return this.statement.executeQuery(query);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("[ERROR] " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}

public ResultSet listTables() {
    try {
        return this.retrieve("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' ORDER BY name");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("[ERROR] " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}

public boolean hasTable(String tableName) {
    try {
        ResultSet rs = this.listTables();
        while (rs.next()) {
            if (rs.getString(1).equals(tableName)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("[ERROR] " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return false;
}

public void update(String query) {
    try {
        if (this.connection != null) {
            this.statement = this.connection.createStatement();
            this.statement.executeUpdate(query);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("[ERROR] " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void dropTable(String tableName) {
    try {
        if (this.hasTable(tableName)) {
            this.update("DROP TABLE " + tableName); // TEST!
        } else {
            System.err.println("[ERROR] Table '" + tableName + "' not found!");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("[ERROR] " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

When I test the dropTable() method, I get an exception saying "database table is locked". I am guessing this is due a non-closed SELECT statement that possibly gets called in the hasTable() method. As far as I know the database tables are locked even when retrieval queries are run so that the tables cannot be updated while others are trying to select data. But how to solve this, I could't be sure. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is your environment but you should use a datasource with a connection pool and retrieve and close a connection for each transaction.
 The perfect way may be to use a container (Spring or Java EE one) and let him manage transaction for you so you don't mind about managing JDBC resources properly. You can also specify whether or not allowing update for a current transaction and manage additional transaction properties like isolation.
 If you absolutely want to use jdbc directly, the best practice is still to close the connection after usage. If you prefer for obscure reasons to keep your read connection alive i would advise to use 2 different users, one granted with read only access and another one for update whose connections should be systematically closed after each call.
In all case you must take care of properly release connection and eventual prepared statements after usage or you will experiment dead locks and / or memory leaks.

cf. http://javarevisited.blogspot.fr/2012/08/top-10-jdbc-best-practices-for-java.html

Comment: I am actually looking into Hibernate.

Comment: But if I were to use JDBC directly, would I have to use static methods (which will open a connection to the database, run a given query, and close the connection)? Currently, I am using an object class with a java.sql.Connection instance variable which does not really get closed.

Comment: Imho it's the best practice indeed. You can let the connection opened and reuse it for all a conversation but you must close it when conversation ends. It's easier to ensure the release of resource by closing its after each use anyway, otherwise use a container like spring to delegate the job.

Comment: I was only leaving the connection open because I thought opening and closing the connection for every transaction would cause overhead. I will apply resource management and test again. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @temelm: yes, opening and closing *does* cost performance, but that's what a connection pool is for: it reduces that cost to practically zero.